# how to get right src for picasso

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I save jpeg file to disk  /storage/emulated/0/myapp

Then insert an image

```
String ms= MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), f.getAbsolutePath(), f.getName(), f.getName());
```

and get: content://media/external/images/media/12878

When I try to load this jpeg to ImageView

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(ms).into((ImageView)view);
```

it doesn't load. I tried "/storage/emulated/0/myapp" too.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(f).into((ImageView)view);
```

The `load()` function accepts Uri, File, String or int as arguments

https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java#L190

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the path with the `"file://"` scheme:

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("file://"+ms).into((ImageView)view);
```

...or convert it to a `File` object.

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(new File(ms)).into((ImageView)view);
```